# Find number of rows between current cell and last cell with matching value in a column

Tags: google-sheets

I have a Google Sheet assigning shifts to employees:

```
10/1/2023   Sunday      Smith
10/2/2023   Monday      Baker
10/3/2023   Tuesday     Johnson
10/4/2023   Wednesday   Smith
10/5/2023   Thursday    Johnson
10/6/2023   Friday      Smith
10/7/2023   Saturday    Baker
10/8/2023   Sunday      Johnson
10/9/2023   Monday      Johnson
10/10/2023  Tuesday     Smith
10/11/2023  Wednesday   Baker
10/12/2023  Thursday    Baker
10/13/2023  Friday      Johnson
```

I would like to add an additional column to the right that displays a `number` representing the `number of days since last shift`.

The first row would be `0` of course because `Smith` has not had a shift yet. But next to `Smith` on `10/4/2023` there should be a `3`.

Similary, for `Baker` on `10/2/2023`, this would be `0` because `Baker` has not had a shift yet. But next to `Baker` on `10/7/2023` there should be a `5`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here you have an option that looks row by row to the value in reverse order with XMATCH:

```
=BYROW(C1:C,LAMBDA(each,IF(each="","",IFERROR(ROW(each)-XMATCH(each,C1:OFFSET(each,-1,0),0,-1),0))))
```

[image]

Comment: This is great. As an added bonus, is there anyway to make it check the sheet prior to it in order of sheets? Assuming the prior sheet represents the previous month and is formatted identically.

Comment: Unfortunately there's no inbuilt function to find names of sheets. But if you place the name of the prior sheet in some cell you could do it, something like: `=BYROW(C1:C,LAMBDA(each,IF(each="","",IFERROR(ROW(each)-XMATCH(each,C1:OFFSET(each,-1,0),0,-1),IFERROR(1+COUNTA(INDIRECT(Z1&"!C:C"))-XMATCH(each, Indirect (Z1&"!C:C"),0,-1),0)))))` where Z1 is that cell